# How to fix the bone axes?

Tags: armature

In Ik bone constraint for leg ,when i tried to move it, it goes in different side.how to align the bone axes? I don't know whether it was axes problem or someother thing.In which direction should leg bone axes be oriented.

Comment: My guess would be the **Pole Angle** of the IK Bone Constraint is wrong. Look on the IK constraint settings under the Bone Constraint tab and try rotating the **Pole Angle** + or - 90 or 180 degrees.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but its not working.